# Unable to install libjack-dev

Tags: package-management, jack

I am on Ubuntu 14.04. 64-bit and I am trying to install linuxband. To do I need to install the package libjack-dev, but when I do so I obtain the following message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an 
impossible  situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjack-dev : Depends: libjack0 (= 1:0.121.3+20120418git75e3e20b-2.1ubuntu1) but it is 
not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The point is that I do have the other libjack-jackd2 installed for example, but when I run the ./configure for linuxband I get:

```
checking for JACK_MIDI_NEEDS_NFRAMES... no
```

Which is the only no in the list. When I run the make, it generates a plethora of undefined references (examples:

```
src/main/c/linuxband-player.c: In function ‘main’:
src/main/c/linuxband-player.c:768:2: warning: ‘g_thread_init’ is deprecated (declared at
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/deprecated/gthread.h:261) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
g_thread_init(NULL);
^
```

or later

```
linuxband-player.c:(.text+0x50b): undefined reference to `jack_transport_query'
linuxband-player.c:(.text+0x586): undefined reference to `jack_transport_query' 
linuxband-player.c:(.text+0x5a1): undefined reference to `jack_last_frame_time'
linuxband-player.c:(.text+0x615): undefined reference to `jack_last_frame_time'
linuxband-player.c:(.text+0x672): undefined reference to `smf_peek_next_event'
linuxband-player.c:(.text+0x6b5): undefined reference to `smf_event_is_metadata
```

and so on)

until it ends in:

```
 /tmp/ccrh0o5V.o:remote_control.c:(.text+0xf01): more undefined references to `g_log' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [target/linuxband-player] Error 1
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Well, it's a shame this has been declared as duplicate so I cannot post an answer, because there is a specific answer in terms of `jack` (and not in terms of `apt` package management per se). I also had the same problem, but I noticed on http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libjack-dev this: "*Packages providing libjack-dev: libjack-jackd2-dev*"; so I just did `sudo apt-get install libjack-jackd2-dev` instead, and I didn't have the `Depends: libjack0` problem anymore.

Comment: @sdaau Thank you for this! You just saved me a lot of hassle!

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar case, where `libjack0` will not **automatically** install because `skype:i386` was messing up with it (because Skype has no 64-bit version for Linux).

The solution for me simply was to force it:

```
sudo apt-get install libjack0
```

Then it asked me to confirm installation of `libjack0` which meant the **uninstalling** of a few other conflicting programs (including Skype in my specific case). It then did install `libjack-dev` smoothly (which for me was a requirement for building Audacity).