# specifying PPA version for apt-get build-dep?

Tags: apt, package-management, compiling, ppa

On Ubuntu 14.04 I want to rebuild the package `ardour` from source, and I've found a suitable version in a PPA, and I've activated its sources (`deb-src` line in the right file somewhere in `/etc/apt/sources.list*`); I can install the package from PPA fine (but there is a bug that requires recompile).

At this point, `apt-cache` reports the versions in the PPA:

```
$ apt-cache showpkg ardour
Package: ardour
Versions: 
1:4.7.270+r15291.42~ubuntu14.04.1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_dobey_audiotools_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-i386_Packages)
...
1:4.7.270+r15280.42~ubuntu14.04.1 (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
...
1:2.8.16+git20131003-1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/dk.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_binary-i386_Packages)
...
Provides: 
1:4.7.270+r15291.42~ubuntu14.04.1 - 
1:4.7.270+r15280.42~ubuntu14.04.1 - 
1:2.8.16+git20131003-1 - 
Reverse Provides: 
ardour-i686 1:2.8.16+git20131003-1
```

Furthermore, if I want to download the source package, I get the right one:

```
$ apt-get source ardour
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Need to get 10.5 MB of source archives.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dobey/audiotools/ubuntu/ trusty/main ardour 1:4.7.270+r15291.42~ubuntu14.04.1 (tar) [10.5 MB]
...
```

So far, so good. But, when I try to install the build dependencies via `build-dep`, I get this:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep ardour
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjack-dev : Depends: libjack0 (= 1:0.121.3+20120418git75e3e20b-2.1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for ardour could not be satisfied.
```

This is wrong - this `ardour` uses `libjack2` - and if I proceed to `sudo apt-get install libjack0`, that action will remove both `libjack2` and `ardour`.

I've seen in `man apt-get` that I can specify version of a package for `build-dep`, but somehow it doesn't work:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep ardour=4.7.270+r15291.42~ubuntu14.04.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Can not find version '4.7.270+r15291.42~ubuntu14.04.1' of package 'ardour'
E: Unable to find a source package for ardour

$ sudo apt-get build-dep ardour=4.7.270
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Can not find version '4.7.270' of package 'ardour'
E: Unable to find a source package for ardour
```

So - how can I specify to `apt-get` that I want the `build-dep` for this specific PPA version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `1:` in the version number. It's not for prettifying the output, but is a part of the version - the epoch number. [Why do some packages have extra numbers on the front of their version string?](https://askubuntu.com/q/441879/158442)

Comment: Thanks for that @muru - just figured that out, too; cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the answer, in terms of how I posted the question - first, from the source files, there is:

```
./debian/rules: ARDOUR_VERSION=`head -1 debian/changelog | awk -F'[()]' '{print $$2}'|cut -d~ -f1|cut -d: -f2`
```

Aha, so I need to see head of `debian/changelog` which is in this case:

```
ardour (1:4.7.270+r15291.42~ubuntu14.04.1) trusty; urgency=low
```

So, basically, the `1:` prefix also needs to be included, which I left out above:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep ardour=1:4.7.270+r15291.42~ubuntu14.04.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjack-dev : Depends: libjack0 (= 1:0.121.3+20120418git75e3e20b-2.1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for ardour=1:4.7.270+r15291.42~ubuntu14.04.1 could not be satisfied.
```

However, there are still dependency problems (EDIT: solution for them is in my comment in [Unable to install libjack-dev - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526385/unable-to-install-libjack-dev#comment1120059_526385) - use `libjack-jackd2-dev` instead) -- but at least it is clear now it is not due to a wrong version reference...